# Corona SDK: Moving a player Up and Down

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have a player who is navigating in space. Since it is space, there is not gravity therefore no parabolic trajectory. The player is just going in a horizontal line from left to right. The player is not actually moving, but the background is, so it looks like he is. The x value is fixed.

I have 2 buttons that help the player avoid obstacles like asteroids. One button gives the player upward force, the other one downward force. The following are the functions called when those buttons are pressed.

```
function moveUp( event )
        if event.phase == "ended" then
```

```
            player:applyForce(0, 8, player.x, player.y)
            player:setSequence("jump")
            jumpChannel = audio.play(jumpSound)
        end
    return true
end
```

function moveDown( event )
        if event.phase == "ended" then

`player:applyForce(0, -8, player.x, player.y)
            player:setSequence("jump")
            jumpChannel = audio.play(jumpSound)
        end
    return true
end`

The problem with this implementation is that whenever a force is applied the player keeps going in that direction. Then you have to apply force in the opposite direction and he will keep going in that direction forever. That is not what I want. What I want is :

- when UP is pressed, player goes up for certain value (say 50 px) in Y. Then the player keeps going in the horizontal direction from left to right in the new altitude.
- When DOWN is pressed, player goes down certain value.  Then the player keeps going in the horizontal direction from left to right in the new altitude.

What is the best way to accomplish this? Can I do this using the applyForce function or is there another method? Thanks in advance for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remember that F=ma: if force applied is 0, a is 0, which means velocity does not change. You have two choices:

1. apply an opposite force that will decrease the speed, and stop when speed is 0. Every Body has myBody.linearDamping factor which you could set to non-zero. If that doesn't work, you can apply your own damping: you make it proportional to Body velocity, so you need an enterFrame event handler that updates the force based on current velocity:

   ```
   function enterFrame(e)
       local v = player:getLinearVelocity()
       player:applyForce(- a * v)
   end
   ```

   Here the "a" is damping, some arbitrary number (0 is what you have now; the larger it is, the faster the player will return to 0 velocity). I haven't checked whether the applyForce() is additive (adds to existing forces) or absolute (replaces existing). But you get the idea.
2. directly move the player:

   ```
   function moveUp( event )
       if event.phase == "ended" then
           player:setLinearVelocity(0, 8) -- pixels/sec
   ```

   You will still need an enterFrame handler to monitor position and setLinearVelocity(0,0) when desired position reached.

You will get smoother, more "realistic" motion with option 1.

Comment: Using force is always smoother and more realistic. The linearDamping factor is working like charm. Thanks dude, I really appreciate it!